# Camera Inactive After click render button

Tags: cycles-render-engine, camera

I have encountered a weird issue with the blender. Here is my scene view before rendering. [image: before render]As you can see the camera is set as the active camera. However, after I click the render button the camera is inactive and it renders a random angle as there is no active camera.  [image: after render]

Answer (score 0):

Once check that there is no other camara in render scene. check in the hidden folder u might get the solution. if the problem gets continue then upload the blend file I'll take look on it.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I double-checked and there is no second camera. Here is link to my blend file. Thank you again for the help! https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xXnWfUDs9FHh54-R76dvClv7gWhbWMIP